# Popen wait en simultaneo Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo dos bloques de múltiples procesos.
el bloque a realiza la ejecución del primer `Popen` para todos los items de la lista.

Necesito que dicho `Popen` corra en simultaneo todas las consolas y una vez que terminen todas las consolas lanzar el siguiente `Popen`.

El problema que tengo es que con el `.wait()` se frena todo y no me permite realizar lo que necesito. Utilice `.wait()` para esperar a que termine el primer bloque pero en vez de hacer esto espera a que termine cada consola del primer bloque.

Código:

```
lista = [0,1,2]

for item in lista:
    p = Popen(
        'python social_networks\\superWrapperAsync.py --conf_file {0}'.format(
            'conf\\' + file_account_name_sep + '.json'
        ),
        creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
    )
    # p.wait()
    """
    os.chdir('utils\\SlideMyProfiles_banner\\')
    p = Popen(
        'python3 SlidesMain.py {0}'.format(
            file_account_name_sep + '_' + scorecard + '.json'
        ),
        creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
    )
    os.chdir('..')
    os.chdir('..')
    """
    break
```

Comment: Necesitas un ciclo for para cada llamada a Popen. No obstante no entiendo para que quieres el ciclo infinito while... con el tu for solo itera para el primer elemento de la lista... ¿O lo rompes en algún momento? Por cierto ultiprocessing.Process() no hace absolutamente nada...

Comment: la acabo de editar como dices. Mi lista tiene 3 elementos. Cada elemento tiene la ejecucion de 2 consolas aunque la segunda consola no puede iniciar hasta que la primera haya terminado. Por eso necesito que se abra en simultaneo las 3 consolas y que cuando terminen se abran las que le siguen @FJSevilla

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres lanzar todos los subprocesos, que corran paralelamente y esperar a que todos terminen, debes agregar cada proceso a una lista y luego recorrerla llamado a `wait` por cada proceso.

Para ejecutar la segunda tanda de subprocesos cuando todos los primeros han terminado debes usar dos `for`. El primero itera sobre la lista y lanza los tres subprocesos, luego se espera a que terminen todos y a continuación el segundo `for` itera otra vez sobre la lista y lanza los otros tres subprocesos.

```
lista = [0,1,2]


subpross = [] 
for item in lista:
    p = Popen(
        'python social_networks\\superWrapperAsync.py --conf_file {0}'.format(
            'conf/' + file_account_name_sep + '.json'
        ),
        creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
    )
    subpross.append(p)

for p in subpross:
    p.wait()

subpross = [] 
for item in lista:
    p = Popen(
        'python3 SlidesMain.py {}{}{}{}'.format(
            file_account_name_sep, '_', scorecard, '.json'
        ),
        creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
    )

    subpross.append(p)

for p in subpross:
    p.wait()
```

Si la lista sola la usas para itera `n` veces, usa `range` en su lugar:

```
iteraciones = range(3)

for _ in iteraciones:
   ...
```

Comment: Espectacular! Gracias!